# Authentication with FSharp.Data.Http

Tags: f#, f#-data

Is there a way to do `https` authentication using FSharp.Data? I am trying to dowload a `json` file from this non public API. My `https` skills are poor, so I might be missing something obvious. So far I tried:

```
#r "../../../bin/FSharp.Data.dll"    
open FSharp.Data
open System    

let url = "https://app.sablono.com/api/projectStatus.xsjs?project=350f83c2-3f3d-49dc-90ec-cf22d1562c3c2"
let username = "xxx"
let password = "yyy"

let addLogin (req: Net.HttpWebRequest) =
    req.Credentials <- new Net.NetworkCredential(username,password)
    req

let txt = Http.RequestString (url ,customizeHttpRequest = addLogin)
```

A download in a browser works just fine on https://app.sablono.com/api/projectStatus.xsjs?project=350f83c2-3f3d-49dc-90ec-cf22d1562c3c2

**Edit:**
I now have this Support Info:

```
1. GET - https://app.sablono.com/sap/hana/xs/formLogin/token.xsjs

with RequestHeader : X-CSRF-Token:Fetch
Reply ResponseHeader : X-CSRF-Token
Can be null.
2. POST - https://app.sablono.com/sap/hana/xs/formLogin/login.xscfunc

With RequestHeader : X-CSRF-Token:<Reply from previous request Request>
and Body as - Form Data: 
xs-username=<USERNAME>&xs-password=<PASSWORD>
ResponseHeader: 
set-cookie:xsId04BF0299185B59F3F3F554A382524B98=A22594ACC3339C4F86FAB57F68CF9FDB; path=/; HttpOnly
set-cookie:sapxslb=6D458FD9581EE04333FC0494D0E9F113; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Some kind of 404. Will post details later..

Answer (score 2):

Unless the API supports Basic Authentication, using NetworkCredential is probably not going to get you anywhere. Based on your extra support info, the body of the request needs to contain your credentials. Do something along the lines of:

```
Http.RequestString("https://app.sablono.com/sap/hana/xs/formLogin/login.xscfunc",
    body = FormValues ["xs-username","username";"xs-password","password"])
```

If all else fails I suggest you inspect your outgoing http requests with something like Fiddler and then compare that with what the API is expecting.

Here is an example of the previous call with added token in the header:

```
Http.RequestString("https://app.sablono.com/sap/hana/xs/formLogin/login.xscfunc",
    body = FormValues ["xs-username","username";"xs-password","password"],
    headers = [ "X-CSRF-Token", "reply from first request" ])
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin! Do you know how to include X-CSRF Token? I get a 403 forbidden: `Request execution failed due to missing or invalid XSRF token`

Comment: I've added another example with the XSRF token included as a header.

Comment: So I have to make another webrequest first to get the Token ?

Comment: Why are there 2 more https path in addtion to one i actually want? Sorry for my very basic web questions.

Comment: If I understand your Support Info above - yes. First request is a GET request to get a token and the 2nd POST is the login.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it to work with FSharp.data Http. so eventually I solved it this way:

```
open System.Text
open System.Net
open System.IO

let get projectId = 
    let un = "USERNAME"
    let pw = "password"    


    let cookieCont = 
        let token = 
            printfn "getting token.."
            let req1 = HttpWebRequest.Create "https://app.sablono.com/sap/hana/xs/formLogin/token.xsjs" :?> HttpWebRequest
            req1.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-Token", "Fetch") //You have to add the X-CSRF-Token = Fetch so that the system can reply with the other token   
            let resp = req1.GetResponse()
            resp.Headers.Get("X-CSRF-Token") //The first time the token is "unsafe"

        let jar = new CookieContainer()
        let req2 = HttpWebRequest.Create "https://app.sablono.com/sap/hana/xs/formLogin/login.xscfunc" :?> HttpWebRequest
        let byteArray = 
            let postData = "xs-username=" + un + "&xs-password=" + pw
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

        req2.CookieContainer <- jar
        req2.Method <- "POST"
        req2.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-Token", token)
        req2.ContentType <-"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=UTF-8"
        req2.ContentLength <- int64 byteArray.Length

        //Put username and password inside the body
        use dataStream = req2.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)

        let _ = // this is to avoid 401 error
            let login_resp = req2.GetResponse()
            login_resp.GetResponseStream() 

        dataStream.Close()
        jar

    printfn "downloading JSON .."     
    let req3 =  HttpWebRequest.Create ("https://app.sablono.com/api/projectStatus.xsjs?project=" + projectId)  :?> HttpWebRequest
    req3.AutomaticDecompression <- DecompressionMethods.GZip
    req3.CookieContainer <- cookieCont
    req3.ContentType <- "application/jsoncharset=UTF-8"
    req3.Accept <- "application/json"

    let resultJSON = 
        let resp = req3.GetResponse()
        let respStream = resp.GetResponseStream()
        use reader = new StreamReader(respStream)
        reader.ReadToEnd()

    resultJSON
```

Comment: I gave up and used a work-around isn't a particularly helpful answer to this question.  It would be better to just leave it open and make a comment on the question that you used a work-around instead.